# Arduino programming using USB download fails on Windows 2000

Tags: serial-port, usb, arduino

I have a number of Windows 2000 systems that we are trying to use to program the new Arduino Uno and Mega devices.  These boards now come with a USB connection, an upgrade from the prior [FTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI).  I'm not able to download the Arduino code into the board from a Windows 2000 system

The supplied drivers are *.inf files that modify the standard USB driver that comes with Windows (in this case Windows 2000).

I go through the process of setting the port, setting the device and doing the download.  The download fails, and the apparent error is that the PC can not communicate with the board.  I've checked the port, adjusted the baud rates, etc.  I've even moved the port number from a high port number (ie COM12) to a lower port (COM2) without any success.  I do see activity on the rec/xmt lights on the Arduino board, so some type of data is being sent and received.

I'm looking for:

Someone who has been able to download files from Windows 2000 to the Arduino

or

A way to shim inside the USB driver to be able to watch the traffic going up and down to the board so I can continue to debug this.

or

Some general tips for things to look at in the .inf file that need to be set/not set to make it work on Windows 2000.

I know the boards work I've used them on a different set of Windows XP systems. So I know to some extent the install is good and that most of what I have works.

Full dumps can be found on the Arduino forum, http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1291090110/.

This is the information produced by the AVRDude program while it's trying to download the code.

Comment: Belongs either to electronics.stackexchange.com or to superuser.com

Comment: Thanks, posted it to electronics.stackexchange.com.  Superuser.com didn't seem to have any similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a long shot, but I jsut recentlz had problems uploading too. Fist of all, how long is the USB cabele you are uploading from? Mine in one case was too long and th arduino woul lose sync. Secondly, and this might just be a silly oversight (like i did) do you have things wired in the digital pin 0 and 1? These are used for the communication, and if there is anything else plugged in to them the upload will also fail.

As I said, long shot but those were two errors I had.